# fetching from DB and store them in a new array PHP

Tags: php

I am fetching data from my DB and they look like this:

```
[{"0":"1","key-1":"1","1":"1","key-2":"1","2":"1","key-3":"1","3":"1","key-4":"1"}]
```

where the key-1 are the name of the column. (I only have one entry so).

I want to extract only the column values and save them into a new array that will output like this:

```
{"key-1":"1","key-2":"1","key-3":"1","key-4":"1"}
```

I want it to look exactly like this and not :  `[{"key-1":"1","key-2":"1","key-3":"1","key-4":"1"}]`

I tried this:

```
$cart["key-1"]=$output["key-1"];
```

where $output is the outcome of the DB that shown first (the one with []).

and the $cart is the new array I want.

Both are declared as:

```
$cart=array();
$output=array();
```

and `$output[]=$row` where row is the result of the DB fetch. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, I've substituted the database row for a string here, and made use of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) and [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode)

```
$data = '[{"0":"1","key-1":"1","1":"1","key-2":"1","2":"1","key-3":"1","3":"1","key-4":"1"}]';

// convert to an array
$data = json_decode($data, true);

// create new array here
$cart = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
{
    foreach ($data[$i] as $k => $v)
    {
        if (strpos($k, 'key') !== FALSE)
        {
            $cart[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}

echo $cart['key-1'] . '<br/>';

echo json_encode($cart);
```

Output:

```
1
{"key-1":"1","key-2":"1","key-3":"1","key-4":"1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very chaotically asked question.
From what I gathered you want maybe this..?

```
$cart=array();
foreach ($output as $index=>$value){
  if stripos($index,"key-"){
    cart[$index]=$value;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not chaotically at all. I want to get only the values from the column and store them in a new array. What is complicated in this?? I will try your answer.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I didn't realize it was JSON and assumed it was just an array. Dale's answer seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get only column names ;)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_of_query))
{
    echo $row['key-1'];
    echo $row['key-2'];
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks with that. I also want my ooutput not to have this [] in front of it. because i need that output to be in that format. ( start with {}). I know almost nothing about php so I am unaware of what is the difference between [] and {} but I need it in that format({}).

Comment: You return a `json` from db? I mean, I understood your question like this: You tried to fetch some rows from DB, and they came in an array with both numbered(indexed) arrays and column-named key-value paired arrays. So my code is a solution to the fetching "problem" like this... If you have a json, then you just have to call `json_encode()` on `$output_array[0]` and then loop through its returned value, and get only the column names.